# Why is this statement problematic?

Tags: javascript, css

If i keep a key button like A or S pressed down for a few seconds without lifting my finger, the transform effect 'sticks' and the class of playing doesn't get removed. If i simply tap A the class Playing is added and then removed. I noticed if i comment out a certain statement it works like it's supposed to. Why? (add the commented out statement to see what i mean).

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dWpxqg

```js
// If i keep a key button like A or S pressed down all the time, eventually the transform effect (yellow border appearing) doesn't go away. If i simply tap A a class of Playing is added and then removed. I noticed that if i comment out a certain statement it works like it's supposed to. Why?



function removeTransition(e) {
    // COMMENTED STATEMENT BELOW IS PROBLEMATIC.
    // if(e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
    this.classList.remove('playing');
}
function playSound(e) {
    const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    if(!audio) return;
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
    key.classList.add('playing');
}

const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
window.addEventListener('keydown', playSound);
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit; }

html {
  height: 100%; }
  html body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    color: white; }

.root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  background: url("../img/crowd.jpg") bottom center;
  background-size: cover; }

.section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1; }

.key {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all .7s ease;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); }
  .key kbd {
    padding: 5px 10px 0 10px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 3rem; }
  .key span {
    color: gold;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 0.7rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: sans-serif; }

.playing {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border-color: #ffc600;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem #ffc600; }

.k-grp-1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; }

footer {
  background-color: #303F9F; }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="root">
        <section class="section">
            <div class="keys">
                <div class="k-grp-1">
                    <div data-key="65" class="key">
                        <kbd>A</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">clap</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="83" class="key">
                        <kbd>S</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">hihat</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="68" class="key">
                        <kbd>D</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">kick</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="70" class="key">
                        <kbd>F</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">openhat</span>
                    </div>


                    <div data-key="71" class="key">
                        <kbd>G</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">boom</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="k-grp-2">
                    <div data-key="72" class="key">
                        <kbd>H</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">ride</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="74" class="key">
                        <kbd>J</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">snare</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="75" class="key">
                        <kbd>K</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">tom</span>
                    </div>
                    <div data-key="76" class="key">
                        <kbd>L</kbd>
                        <span class="sound">tink</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer> Footer</footer>
    </div>

    <audio data-key="65" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
    <audio data-key="83" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>
    <audio data-key="68" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
    <audio data-key="70" src="sounds/openhat.wav"></audio>
    <audio data-key="71" src="sounds/boom.wav"></audio>
    <audio data-key="72" src="sounds/ride.wav"></audio>
    <audio data-key="74" src="sounds/snare.wav"></audio>
    <audio data-key="75" src="sounds/tom.wav"></audio>
    <audio data-key="76" src="sounds/tink.wav"></audio>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to demonstrate the problem with the specific conditional statement, by adding a couple of lines in your event callback like so:

```
var counts = {};

function removeTransition (e) {

    // if ( (e.propertyName === 'transform') ) {
    //  return;
    // }

    if (typeof counts[e.propertyName] === 'undefined') {
        counts[e.propertyName] = 1;
    } else {
        counts[e.propertyName] = counts[e.propertyName] + 1;
    }

    // console.log(e.propertyName);
    this.classList.remove('playing');

    console.log(counts);
}
```

I simply added a map to keep track of the distinct number of different values the **e.propertyName** attribute can have while you hold the button pressed continuously.

For example if I hold down the 'A' key for 5" and then stop I get the following measurement:

```
{
  "transform": 29,
  "border-right-color": 58,
  "border-bottom-color": 58,
  "border-left-color": 58,
  "border-top-color": 58,
  "box-shadow": 30
}
```

As you will notice, from the total number of times the **removeTransition()** function was called - triggered by the *transitionend* event - the *transform* value occurred almost half of the times compared to the rest of the CSS attributes.

This means that in the case that someone holds a button pressed (doesn't matter how long) the *keydown* event will continuously be triggered and the **playing** class will in turn be added to the element.  The problem is though, that if you only check for the **'transform'** CSS property to be received you will catch it half of the times compared to the rest of the CSS properties and mainly due its asynchronous nature, as it takes longer time to complete.

Comment: arigato gosaimasu, also interesting that box shadow is slow too.